# Why does Clojure recur think it should only have one argument?

Tags: clojure

Edit:

The answer to this is I was looking at the function, not loop parameters.

In the second of the following two functions, I cannot figure out why the recur thinks it so only supposed to be passed one argument.

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 1 args, got: 2, compiling:(/home/cnorton/projects/clojure/clj_in_action/mr1/src/mr1.clj:84)

I am not seeing what is incorrect.

```
(defn determine-rover-move
    [rover-coord mov]

    (println rover-coord mov)
    (cond
        (= \L mov) (assoc rover-coord 0 (adj-compass-posL (first rover-coord)))
        (= \R mov) (assoc rover-coord 0 (adj-compass-posR (first rover-coord)))
        (= \M mov) (mov-rover rover-coord)

    ))


(defn execute-each-move
    [moves rover-coord]
    (loop [mov moves]
        (if (nil? mov)
            rover-coord
            (recur (rest moves) (determine-rover-move rover-coord mov)))))
```

Comment: OK I see the problem now. The loop only has one argument. I was looking at the function parameters.

Comment: Maybe provide the answer to your own question as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Actually, I was going to and the note with answering your own question said better to use a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part is the section here:

```
(loop [mov moves] ...)
```

This code fragment is binding `mov` to `moves` from the outer function scope. The use of `recur` comes inside the `loop` though, so `recur` expects only one parameter according to the `loop` definition.

Comment: "moves" is technically not a var as in a Clojure Var, but just a symbol bound to a value provided by a function call to "execute-each-move"